# Bubble chart Hover

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

Can we remove 'Series 1' displaying on top or modify it?
Also, can we limit the number of values displayed on hover and add a view more option?
[Bubble Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSirZ.png)

We were tring to remove or modify the 'Series' header 1 but were not successful

Comment: This doesn't look like standard salesforce report chart. You're probably using a custom visualisation library. chart.js? d3? vis.js? You'll have to consult the library's documentation or at least change tags in your question to give people observing say d3 tag a chance to see your question... Try to find the source code of this component? Visualforce page? It likely references a 'static resource" with the javascript library

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's great to have you here. However, your question might benefit from some improvements. Could you provide more context and be more specific about your issue? This will help you get better responses. Please read following guide: [How To: Write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Afterwards [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) your post and improve it. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

To remove the 'Series 1' text, edit the `tooltip.headerFormat` property:

```
tooltip: {
  headerFormat: ''
}
```

The rest of the content can be edited freely by using one of the options: `pointFormat`, `pointFormatter` or `formatter`.

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eu489t7L/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.headerFormat

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat